# Why are my integers (pulled from an array) not being checked in my if statement properly?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I've got an app playing sound files and I'm using integers to calculate the difference in pitch. The user responds with what they think the answer is and both the actual results and the user's answers are stored in NSMutableArrays. I've wrapped them in NSNumber objects but when I'm pulling them out in the code below, it seems as though the integer value is always 0 and regardless of what the user inputs, the inputCount is going up as though they matched. Can anyone explain this? I'm desperate.

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
if ([[userAnswers objectAtIndex: i] intValue] == [[intervalResults objectAtIndex: i] intValue]) {
    inputCount++;
    self.inputCountDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", inputCount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the bracket  ( ) this will not work [ ] use this

Comment: Do you mean use
    if [[[userAnswers objectAtIndex: i] intValue] == [[intervalResults objectAtIndex: i] intValue]) {
        NSLog(@"%i", [[userAnswers objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
        inputCount++;
        self.inputCountDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", inputCount];

Because the if statement expects () so I get an error using [].